# How can I document type parameters in Python?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, type-variables

I'd like to document what `T` means in this class

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T]):
    pass
```

I could document `T` with `T.__doc__ = "Represents ..."` but I might want to use `T` it in several unrelated classes.

Is there any standard way to document it for a given class/function etc? Ideally using sphinx & reST.

I'm thinking something at the same level as sphinx's `:param:`, but for types, along the lines of [scaladoc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html)'s `@tparam`

Comment: Can't you document in general with multiline strings?

Comment: @BlueRineS I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean like docstrings or multi-line strings. The regular stuff that people use for documentation. But you probably need something more advanced?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), about all you can say about it is `TypeVar('T')  # Can be anything` — i.e. it's a generic. Class `A` is derived from it, but likely requires or assumes that it to have some specific properties. You can document what those are in class `A`'s own documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You could document it through the multiline string as suggested in this way:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T]):
"""
Description of the class and his input T

Inputs:
    T : what is T? the type of T

Returns:
    res 

"""
```

And you could call the documentation as:

```
A.__doc__
```

or

```
help(A)
```